# Что не так с проверкой input на пустоту?

Tags: javascript

Функция не проходит тест в случае  for input = []: expected [ 0, 0 ] to deeply equal []. Ожидается [ 0, 0 ] - так она это и отдает в случае input = []. Разве нет?

```
   function countPositivesSumNegatives(input) {
      var positives =0;
      var negatives =0;
      let resultArr = [0,0];  
      let i =0;
      
      if (input===null || input.length===0){
        return resultArr;
      }
       
      while (i<input.length){
        if (input[i]>0) {
           positives++;
         }
        if (input[i]<0) {
          negatives = input[i]+negatives;           
        }     
        i++
      }
      
    resultArr [0]=positives;
    resultArr [1]=negatives;  
      
    return resultArr;
    }
```

Comment: что мешает проверить?

Comment: Что проверить? Что отдает? Проверял, отдает массив [0,0]

Comment: Вам подтвердить что ваш выщитаный результат верный? Перевести запись? Добавте задачу и функцию тестов. По данным все ок, чего надо - не понятно